# Ошибка в конструкторе копирования

Tags: c++

Есть следующий упрощённый класс:

```
struct ID {
    int id;
    std::string string_id;

    template<typename String>
    explicit ID(String&& string_id) : string_id{std::forward<String>(string_id)}, id{std::stoi(string_id)} {}

    ID(const ID& other) : string_id{other.string_id}, id{std::stoi(other.string_id)} {}
};
```

Вроде как всё нормально, но когда пытаюсь вызвать конструктор копирования, получаю непонятные ошибки из `explicit` конструктора... В чём проблема?

```
ID id1("3x5");
ID id2(id1); // ошибка
```

Comment: "получаю непонятные ошибки" - это какие? Будьте так добры, укажите где и какие ошибки выдает компилятор.

Comment: @Croessmah no matching function for call to ‘stoi(ID&)’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут целая россыпь ошибок:

- параметр функции `string_id` имеет то же имя, что и поле класса, это чревато адской путанницей
- при передаче универсальной ссылки `std::forward(string_id)` пропущен параметр шаблона `String`
- поля класса в списке инициализации указаны не в том порядке, в котором они будут инициализироваться
- в записи `ID id2(id1);` будет более предпочтителен конструктор с универсальной ссылкой, а не копирующий (так как он принимает `ID &`), для исправления достаточно сделать кастование `ID id2(::std::as_const(id1));` или доработать конструктор с универсальной ссылкой использую что-нибудь вроде [`safe_overload`](https://github.com/facebook/fatal/blob/master/fatal/type/impl/safe_overload.h)

Comment: Можно заметить, что порядок объявления полей класса как раз и спасает ситуацию в этом случае. Если бы поля были объявлены в другом порядке, то `string_id{std::forward<String>(string_id)}` мог бы разрушать содержимое исходного `string_id`, после чего `id{std::stoi(string_id)}` уже не работал бы правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, `std::forward` требует явного указания шаблонного аргумента

```
string_id{std::forward<String>(string_id)}
```

Каким образом у вас получилось "все нормально" без вызова конструктора копирования - не ясно.

Во-вторых, ваша универсальная ссылка - "идеальный параметр", который в процессе overload resolution побеждает даже вариант с `const ID&` из-за необходимости квалификационного преобразования (добавления `const`) в последнем. Если вы в своем конструкторе копирования уберете `const`

```
ID(ID& other)
```

то "победит" именно он. А так - побеждает ваш

```
template<typename String> explicit ID(String&& string_id)
```

который в таком случае получается некорректным.

Comment: изменил вопрос, в коде у меня есть, забыл переписать сюда

Comment: так я же вызываю конструктор копирования `ID id2(id1);`

Comment: @staff Ваш шаблонный конструктор подходит лучше, чем конструктор копирования.